# Can I override WebAPI OData service document?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm trying to figure out why the WebAPI implementation of OData doesn't consistently output all actions and procedures to the service document. I would also prefer if the URLs output in the service document would include required & optional parameters.

I will first elaborate the issue I'm hitting with an inconsistent service document:

For example, hitting:

```
http://services.odata.org/V4/(S(r30qiqlnwgbfi2sgesu5l25w))/TripPinServiceRW/
```

will not include the unbound action "ResetDataSource". And running it locally, I actually don't even consistently see the GetNearestAirport function appear consistently.

When I inspect my IEdmModel, the function shows that it should be included in the service document:

```
var desiredElem = edmModel.EntityContainer.Elements.First(e => e.Name == "GetNearestAirport") as EdmFunctionImport;
Console.WriteLine(desiredElem.IncludeInServiceDocument);
```

Can anyone tell me whether or not it is possible to override the generated service document, and whether or not I am missing something as to why the service document is not consistently generating the same output?

For reference, you can also see the github code sample for the TripPin service [here](https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples)

Answer (score 0):

I do not experience the behavior you are seeing regarding the ResetDataSource action and the GetNearestAirport function not appearing in the Metadata Service Document. I have not heard of anyone having that issue. Will chat with the OData team this week about it.

In regards to the overriding of the Metadata Service Document, I do not believe there is any way at this time to change it. Allowing changes to the MSD would not follow the OData protocol but that is a protocol discussion and not a technical. I don't think the OData team thought of a good reason to allow that from a technical aspect.

Comment: To clarify, I'm not talking about the "metadata service document" (Odata-CSDL), in which it will appear, but the root "service document request" ([spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata01/os/complete/part1-protocol/odata-v4.0-errata01-os-part1-protocol-complete.html#_Toc399426783)). - Meaning `http://services.odata.org/V4/(S(r30qiqlnwgbfi2sgesu5l25w))/TripPinServiceRW/` rather than `http://services.odata.org/V4/(S(r30qiqlnwgbfi2sgesu5l25w))/TripPinServiceRW/$metadata` - just to make sure we're on the same page?